# What is the difference between container and docker input in filebeat configuration?

Tags: filebeat, elk

I checked the official document about it but wasn't able to figure out the difference. If anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [docker input documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-input-docker.html), it seems like the `docker` input is being deprecated in favor of a more general `container` input.

[image]

The `container` input is probably a very similar, but it accommodates other containerization technologies aside from docker.